# Memory Load/Save Utility in Code Composer 3.3

Tags: memory, load, save, utility, code-composer

Apologies in advance for the dated software question:

According to Code Composer help documentation the "Memory Load/Save Utility" should be be in the Tools menu. In my Code Composer 3.3 (which I have to use for this project, so I cannot upgrade), does not have this option in the tools menu, or any menu that I could find. It is not greyed out - it is just simply missing as far as I can tell. I've changed every view option to try and enable this.

Can anyone help me figure out how to enable/activate this option? Does the processor need to be in a specific state? Is this a special plug-in that I can't find?

Here is my setup:
Code Composer 3.3, Windows Xp, Using a Spectrum Digital xds510pp JTAG emulator on a TI ARM 9 processor.

Specifically the option is here: 13. Memory Load/Save Utility:
http://www.ti.com/lit/an/spraa07c/spraa07c.pdf

[EDIT] The File > Data > Save - this is not the same as the Memory Load/Save Utility. This sounds similar but does not export the values.

For example, I need to export data at a certain memory address for a certain length into a hex format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow my installation went bad.

I checked the Code Composer Studio Component Manager by running C:\CodeComposer3.3\cc\bin\comp_mgr.exe. Now, in this window un the TI node, there should be numerous plugins and one of which should be: "Memory Save/Load Utility Control..."

For me this was missing.

Repairing the installation via windows control panel did not work. I had to uninstall and then reinstalled. Upon reinstalling a TMS470 driver was reported missing. Not sure why this was.

Again, I uninstalled then complete removed the C:\CodeComposer3.3\ directory, then reinstalled. This time everything seemed to have worked and I do have the Memory Save/Load Utility and it is working.

EDIT:
It should also be noted that the plugins are bundled with the installer and could not be re installed separately.